# jQuery hide all divs that Do NOT contain a particular word in the class

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following piece of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("ul.accordion-section-content li[id*='layers-builder'] button.add-new-widget").click(function () {
    $("#available-widgets-list div[class*='layers-widget']").hide(); 
  });
});
```

The idea behind this code is that if a button that contains the phrase 'layers-builder' is clicked, then all the divs containing the phrase 'layers-widget' in the div `#available-widgets-list` are hidden.

What I need it to do is almost the opposite, i.e. when the button containing the phrase 'layers-builder' is clicked, I need all the divs that DO NOT contain the phrase 'layers-builder' to be hidden.

Comment: unfortunately this won't work as the divs only contain the phrase 'layers-widget' that is not the complete class (the rest of the class is dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("ul.accordion-section-content li[id*='layers-builder'] button.add-new-widget").click(function() {
    $("#available-widgets-list div:not([class*='layers-builder'])").hide();
  });
});
```